# Statistical test gives result different than reality?

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics, histogram

Let's define X as :

[image]

and objects releated to it:

[image]

I want to calculation value of function following, and plot it on the same graph with histogram eigenvalues of Y.

[image]

After that I want to perform chi2gof test to judge weather those two distributions converge to each other or not. I want to use parameter expected with is designed to compare distributions of function and histogram.

**My work so far**

```
clf; 
m=8000;
n=10000;
X=randn(m,n);
Y=X*X'/n;
sd=std(X(:));
l=m/n;
eigs=eig(Y);
lp=sd^2*(1+sqrt(l))^2;
lm=sd^2*(1-sqrt(l))^2;
x=linspace(0.00000001,lp,n);
for i = 1:length(x)
    if (and(x(i) <= lp, x(i) >= lm))
        dv(i) = sqrt((lp-x(i)).*(x(i)-lm))./(2*pi*sd^2*l.*x(i));
    else 
        dv(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

This code fully calculates my function dv. Now to plot it on histogram, and to add sens to it I normalized histogram to have unit area.

```
hold on;
[h, centres] = hist(eigs, 50);
% normalise to unit area
norm_h = h / (numel(eigs) * (centres(2)-centres(1)));
bar(centres, norm_h);
plot(x, dv, "r");
hold off;
```

The result from this code is image following:

[image]

As we can see the dv line really nicely fits the histogram. We can be almost sure that chi square test for same distribution should output p value very close to 1 (it means that samples are from the same distribution). However code

```
[h,p,stats] = chi2gof(dv,'Expected',norm_h);
```

outputs

```
 p =

     0
```

It means that null hypothesis of the same distributions were rejected. My question is - how ? Am I using something incorrectly, or this pvalue is really 0 ?

Comment: I have never used `chi2gof`, but it looks like the syntax with the `'Expected'` option should be different. See the example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html#btv1j1v-9)